# creating shareable virtual usb devices, possible?

Tags: usb, emulation, simulation

not sure if possible but want to get a virtualized copy of a usb device, it's not a hard drive or usb drive, it's a "card scanner" that is used on a game and is quite handy but i always need to have it connected and have it virtualized would be much easier
the reason why i want it shareable is because i'm interested in share it with a few friends
my question is, is there any software that could save a simulated version of it (kinda like daemon tools does with CDs) and use the device tools virtualy?

Comment: Sounds like you want to completely defeat the purpose of two factor authentication.

Comment: sounds like it's not possible, thanks for the totally obvious answer :V